# If 'Play Store' app is not running, IAB fails with "Unable to start service Intent."

Tags: android, android-intent, google-play, android-billing, android-inapp-purchase

I have working In App Billing working in Android: IABv3.

However, it will only operate properly if the 'Play Store' app is running in the background.

If I kill the 'Play Store' app, then starting up IAB will fail with this error:

`W/ActivityManager( 1188): Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND pkg=com.android.vending } U=0: not found`

I have followed the sample implementation, I have added the billing permission in the manifest. I also have the aidl file in my project source.

I never noticed this weird behaviour before (I was testing on Android 3.x and 4.x devices only so far. But now on an Android 6.0.1 device, I get this error.)

Using 'Google Play Billing Library' rev 5.

target SDK API 21.

SDK tools rev 25.